# How do I restart a minecraft server stopped with /stop?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm an OP on a Minecraft server. When I was fiddling around with commands, I wrote in `/stop`. I didn't know it would stop the server and now the server won't come back online.
The server owner is never on so he can't do anything. Is there anything I can do to get the server back up? Or do I have to wait for the owner to start it again?

Comment: When you contact the server owner, ask him to set `op-permission-level` to 3 in [server.properties](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server.properties#Minecraft_server_properties). This prevents `/stop` being used from anywhere but the server console itself, without affecting other commands.

Comment: @MrLemon So you are sure that I cannot open it unless the owner does or let's me edit the server setup scripts?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately for you, NBN-Alex's answer is correct.

Comment: @Nick I belive what MrLemon said in his first comment is a "good idea for the server owner to do" _in addition to_ solving the probelm. (For actual solutions, see answers.)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortanly, the only way to start the server again is to access the PC/server/box that was hosting it.  That /stop command is only meant to be used to shutdown the server so the admin can make config changes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't.

But the owner can do something about it. He can end the process, and start the server, or restart the server. If he cannot do that, that's a crappy hosting.